# PHP move_uploaded_file successfully uploads but returns false

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, image-upload

I am trying to create an upload for a picture to a website. I am also trying to resize the image before writing to the directory. The pictures are being uploaded fine, but for whatever reason the move_uploaded_file function returns false, even though the file is actually being uploaded. Please see some of my code below:

```
$fileType = $_FILES['photo_one']['type'];

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $pic=($_FILES['photo_one']['name']); 
$tmppic = ($_FILES['photo_one']['tmp_name']);
$front=uniqid (rand (),false);
$newpic=$front.'_'.$pic;
$newtmppic=$front.'_'.$tmppic;



if($fileType == 'image/jpg' || $fileType == 'image/jpeg' )
{
$tmppic = ($_FILES['photo_one']['tmp_name']);
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmppic);
}
else if($fileType == 'image/png')
{
$tmppic = ($_FILES['photo_one']['tmp_name']);
$src = imagecreatefrompng($tmppic);
}
else 
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($tmppic);
}


list($width,$height)=getimagesize($tmppic);

$newwidth='700px';
$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "../secure/profile_images/"; 
 $newtarget = $target . basename($newpic); 

imagejpeg($tmp,$newtarget,100);

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $newtarget)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
header('Location: Picture.php#A1');
 } 
 else { 
  //Gives an error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 }
```

Instead of being redirected to Picture.php, the screen returns, "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file." However, when I go to view the picture on the website, I can see that the image is successfully there. I checked the error logs and nothing shows in there either so I am at a loss. Any advice or thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: try first move uploaded file or file_put_contents if you work with imagick, and then RESIZE image, create thumb or modify file, and save yr modified copy as well mh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you create the image with `imagejpeg($tmp,$newtarget)` which creates the image and store it the specified path and you try to move the same file that is already created and stored on the server. `imagejpeg` will create the image and store it on the server without using `move_uploaded_file` function. if you want to check if the file was created, remove the `move_uploaded_file` function with the following code.

```
//Writes the photo to the server 
if(imagejpeg($tmp,$newtarget,100)) 
{ 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 header('Location: Picture.php#A1');
} 
  else { 
 //Gives an error if its not 
  echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 }
```